# How to create HABTM association with STI model sub-classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, has-and-belongs-to-many, sti

Lets say I have a STI model called `Company`. It has three sub-classes `Firm`, `Client` and `PriorityClient`.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :firms_n_clients, -> { where(type: %w(Firm Client)) }
end
class Firm < Company; end
class Client < Company; end
class PriorityClient < Company; end
```

I have another model called `Country`. Now I want to create  a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between `Country` and `firms_n_clients`(only `Firm` and `Client` type of `Company`). How would it be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at tag:  [Tag:class-table-inheritance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

has_and_belongs_to_many associations accept scopes. Some of them are discussed in the [Ruby on Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference). Assuming the necessary join table exists, the association can be established like so:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :companies, -> { where(type: %w(Firm Client)) }
end

class Firm < Company
    has_and_belongs_to_many :countries
end

class Client < Company
    has_and_belongs_to_many :countries
end
```

Please note the duplicate Code in Client and Firm. This is on purpose, because it reveals explicitly that Clients and Firms have and belong to countries, and PriorityClients do not.

I have not tested the below code, but an even better way to modify the HABTM Association would be to merge the the *firms_n_clients* scope:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :companies, -> { merge(Company.firms_n_clients) }
end
```

This has several advantages: The Country model doesn't need to know about the different Company types, and modifying the scope will affect the association as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now my question is how would be the intermediate table? would it be `companies_countries` with `company_id` and `country_id` or there will be two intermediate tables like `firms_countries` and `clients_countries`?

Comment: @JunanChakma Think of Join Tables as connection between tables, not between models. That's why one table with country_id and company_id is the way to go. `rails generate migration CreateJoinTableCompanyCountry company country` should generate the required migration.